# Second pushed View Controller with UISearchController doesn't receive touches in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I modified `AAPLSearchBarEmbeddedInNavigationBarViewController` in Apple's UICatalog sample code so that it pushes another instance of `AAPLSearchBarEmbeddedInNavigationBarViewController` onto the navigation stack when a cell is selected. In the second view controller the UISearchBar set as the title view of the UINavigationBar (just like the first one) isn't tappable (unlike the first the one). This seems like a bug. How do I fix it? Here is my modified UICatalog code:
https://github.com/stevemoser/UICatalog

Also I tested with with Xcode 6 and 7. It's broken in both.

Comment: Try using the 3D view hierarchy debugger tool to see how things are being drawn when you have a second controller. Probably a red herring, but what happens if you comment out self.definesPresentationContext=YES. It should not really matter as that is for modal presentation, but just in case it is affecting things for some reason.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel you put me on the right track. See my answer.

Comment: I did not like the look of the line. However it should not affect pushed controllers as far as my understanding goes. I assume it is there in case you present the search results in a separate controller modally which will force it below the search bar. Anyway your solution makes sense: only provide the context if you are the top controller.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to set the first VC `self.definesPresentationContext = NO` when navigating away from it and making sure to call `self.definesPresentationContext=YES` in the view did appear so that the visible VC allows defines the presentation context.

Thanks goes to Rory McKinnel who put me on the right track.